# Python next() for 5 examples and store in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a text dataset, and I would like to visualise the first 5 rows into a dataframe. Is there an elegant way to print 5 iterations from next()?

```
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k(root='.data', split=('train', 'valid', 'test'), language_pair=('de', 'en'))

next(train_data)  # How do I print 5 "next" in a loop and send it to a dataframe?
```

And the second part, how could I transpose the tuple, to make it into two columns? Eg; the first part of the tuple would be a column 'German', and the second tuple part as 'English'. Here's what I tried:

```
line1=next(train_data)
pd.DataFrame(list(line1))
```

But this only returns a dataframe with one column, and two rows. I would like the target to be something like this image:

[image: Target output]

Comment: What is `train_data`? Can you do `items = train_data[:5]` to get the first 5 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with itertools islice.

```
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k(root='.data', split=('train', 'valid', 'test'), language_pair=('de', 'en'))

pd.DataFrame(list(islice(train_data,5)), columns=['de','en'])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Question: how does "train_data,5" work?

Comment: Ah okay, I found out: islice(iterable, start, stop, step)